# Repriorização de ordem de pedido

Tags: sql, mysqli, order-by

A repriorizacao seria para que quando o usuário define uma sequencia de prioridade para ser atendido igual a:

A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4

E ele quer repriorizar "D" como "1" faça com quem os subsequentes vão para a posisão inferior ficando

D = 1
A = 2
B = 3
C = 4

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes , script das tabelas , de onde vem a "ordem" etc. Se possível faça um exemplo no sqlfiddle.

Comment: Talvez um simples .... order by ( case when campo='d' then 0 when campo = 'a' then 1 .... else 9 end) asc  ....

Answer (score -3):

Bem para fazer a consulta voce precisara apenas pegar o numero que voce mudou, no seu caso, o D era 4, ent vamos usa-lo de exemplo:

Bem, vou explicar a logica aq, mas se quiser, pule ao fim do texto para a QUERY,
digamos que temos um array ao inves de uma db [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9] e ao inves de puxar um elemento pra frente, voce esta apenas eliminando um, retirando o 7 por exemplo, ficaria [1,2,3,4,5,6,    8,9], para resolver esse rombo voce apenas pega todos os numeros a esquerda (numeros menores) da posiçao original e adiciona eles +1

Assim ficando [2,3,4,5,6,7  ,8,9] os 8 e 9 nao mudariam pois sao maiores que 7(posiçao original) assim sobrando a primeira posiçao para o 7(D por exemplo)

Para fazer isso na query precisamos setar na coluna +1 caso a posiçao for maior que 7, obviamente o 7 n seria hardcode mas é o principal é isso

QUERY:

UPDATE tabela SET coluna = coluna+ 1 WHERE posiçao > 7

espero ter ajudado!!